How can I use Next.js with Sass?
There are several related questions to mine, but none that have fixed my issue.
Context
I'm trying to use yarn create next-app (which I thought comes with Sass) to build a web app and then use yarn add sass to add sass support. However, I keeping seeing this error:
To use Next.js' built-in Sass support, you first need to install `sass`.
Run `npm i sass` or `yarn add sass` inside your workspace.

Steps to reproduce:

Run yarn create next-app,
Name the project next-sass-test,
Otherwise use the default options the CLI gives you,
Run cd next-sass-test,
Run mv page.module.css page.module.scss; rm page.module.css (to change the file extenion),
Run yarn add sass at the project root level,
Run next build,
See that it displays the above error,
Run yarn add sass again and we're back to step 8.

I have also tried yarn add node-sass to no avail.

try saving as a dev dependency npm install --save-dev sass
Check official docs once, if required add config settings https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/styling/sass

@ImranRafiqRather I ran it and saved it as a dev dependency, but I still see the error

Also, I keep getting another error Type error: Cannot find module 'next/dist/lib/metadata/types/metadata-interface.js' or its corresponding type declarations. and I'm running the latest software

Are you on github, You can push your code on github so that I will have a look, put node_modules in .gitignore and then push :) Need to look what the matter is dear
